# linear dependence proof using subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

how do you prove if a subset of a set of vectors is linearly dependent, then the entire set is linearly dependent. 
i know that linear dependence means that it can be written as a linear combination.
so i can take 1 vectors from the set and write it as a linear combination of some of the vectors find it to be linearly dependent and do so for the whole and find it to be linearly dependent. 
i do not know how i can prove  without actually resorting to an example and you cant prove by example.

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite formally and suitable for arbitrary diensions: 
Let $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of vectors. Assume the subfamily $\{v_i\}_{i\in J}$ with $J\subset I$ is linearly dependant. That means by definition that there is a family $\{a_i\}_{i\in J}$ of scalars such that almost all $a_i$ are zero and at least one $a_i$ is nonzero and $\sum_{i\in J}a_iv_i=0$. Let $\{b_i\}_{i\in I}$ be the family of scalars given by
$$b_i=\begin{cases}a_i&\text{if }i\in J\\0&\text{if }i\notin J\end{cases} $$
Then one immediatyly verifies that almost all $b_i$ are zero, at least one $b_i$ is nonzero and $\sum_{i\in I}b_iv_i=0$, thus showing that  $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$  is linearly dependant.

Comment: thanks the combination of both answers helped a lot. thank you Sir

Answer (score 2):

It is basically as you say. If you can write one of the vectors as a linear combination of some of the others, you can write it as a linear combination of all the others (just by using zero as the coefficients of the vectors you were not using at the beginning).

Comment: thanks this gave an idea of what to do.thx Sir